# Nginx two virtual hosts on with domain name one in localhost

Tags: nginx, dns, config, virtual-hosts

On my Nginx I've got two hosts.
One with the values
`server_name = www.mydomain.com;
root /var/www/production/myFirstWebSite;` 
and the other with 
`server_name=localhost;
root /var/www/development/mySecondWebSite;`

To my domain registrar account I configured the DNS with two A record "

`www IN A myIP
     IN A myIP`

This is cool, i can reach my first website with www.mydomain.com or mydomain.com.

Now the problem is how to reach my second website which is in development and I don't buy the domain name. And myIP/development/myScondWebSite is no more working ...
I think that the problem come from the DNS entries but I'm not sure.
Do you've got some ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Localhost is your "local" machine. Unless your accessing your development site from that machine you'll never reach the localhost.

Comment: Ok I get it thanks, but so how I can reach my second website, by creating a subdomain ?
Because my distrib is a Debian server without GUI :)

Comment: You can't unless your using the web browser on your Debian server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of ways I could think of to access the localhost one.

- Creating a subdomain instead of localhost
  This is the best one I'd recommend, try doing something like `server_name localhost.mydomain.com`.
  If you need to put further security, you could make it only allow a certain IP(s) or a range of IPs.
- Play with your hosts file
  In this specific case I would not recommend this, because you're messing with `localhost` it self, might break some other stuff on your machine, if it was any other name I could have said it's fine.
- Use an ssh tunnel to the server
  In this method you create a dynamic port on your ssh connection and set your browser to pass all traffic through  tunnel which goes to the server then it's handled from there, so if you run `localhost` for example it would be like running `localhost` from over there, but since this involved a browser setting, you need to remember to disable it after you disconnect the ssh connection otherwise the browser would return an error saying that the proxy server is refusing the connection.
- Using a local Nginx as a proxy
  This one I just  came up with right now, and I can't say If it would work or not, the 3 before I've worked with before and I know they work.
  You'd set a certain domain name that your local nginx would capture and then proxy it to the remote server, but edit the `host` header setting it to localhost instead, that way it would match the `localhost` in the remote machine, if this one works it would not need any setting to be turned on and off every time.

Out of all these, I'd recommend the first one first (if it's an option), then try the last one if you don't want to keep turning things on and off before and after each setting.